# Could not create database using package manager console in .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Im learning .net now and following along the course,my goal is to create CRUD app so i need a database to work with it, i have succesfuly created initial migration but database-update doesnot work

> (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error
> occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
> Application event log for error details.

im getting this error if connection strings look like this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "QuotesAppContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=QuotesAppContext-811c920d-aeb7-4d04-8ba6-5c9a48d8b492;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

i have installed both sql server and sql management on windows 11 without problem
and if i change connection string to this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "QuotesAppContext": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=QuotesAppContext-811c920d-aeb7-4d04-8ba6-5c9a48d8b492;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

deleting \ problem now is

> Unable to create an object of type 'QuotesAppContext'.

so it seems like an endless circle to me, thanks you for your help

write database-update and get database instance working

Comment: In Package Manager Console the command is `Update-Database`

Comment: yep i have tried it too but error's stay the same

Comment: The first error states that something is wrong with your localdb setup. Or maybe the connection string itself. Did you check the Windows Event Logs. If you can share that logs it would be better.

Comment: seems like two types of errors come to event logs first is
'''
LocalDB parent instance version is invalid:
'''

Comment: and second Windows API call RegOpenKeyExW returned error code: 2. Windows system error message is: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is your DbContext by any chance in separate project? If so, did you try to run database update with --project and --startup-project switches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer which have worked for me,find this folder in regedit

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances"
```

and delete everything inside of it,and after that run Update-Database command again everything should work fine
P.S
i have tried reinstalling sql server,adding ports, but this solution worked for me